# What does  mean in calculus of variation?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, gateaux-derivative

In a calculus of variation problem, let functional $J = \ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x, y, y') \,dx $. When $x_1$ and $x_2$ are all fixed, the variation of J are defined by Gâteaux variation:

$\delta J(y, h) = \frac{dJ(y+\epsilon h)}{d\epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$, here $h=h(x)$ is any arbitrary function and $\epsilon$ is a scalar. Then the Euler-Lagrange equation can be derived by making $\delta J(y, h) = 0$.

When $x_1$ and $x_2$ are NOT fixed, the general variation of $J$ is derived by Gelfand Fomain etc. as follows:

[Derivation of general variation of a functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7CaA.png)

[Derivation of general variation of a functional continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHrvy.png)

My question are:

1. Can we derive the general variation of a functional ($x_1$ and $x_2$ are NOT fixed) by using Gâteaux variation? So that we may express $\delta J$ again as a limit or derivative of $\epsilon$?
2. When $x$ is the independent variable, are $d x$ and $\delta x$ different?
3. When $y = y(x)$, what is $\delta y$? Is it true that $\delta y = \epsilon h(x)$? Here $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal scalar and $h(x)$ is any admissible arbitrary function.
4. Is it true that $\delta$ operates just like the differential $d$ in deriving equations? What are the differences?

I tried to derive $\delta J$ by making J a function of four independent scalar variables, which are $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3$ and $\epsilon_4$.The meaning of these variables can be seen in the following figure:
[[image: Construct of a smooth function <span class=]$y(x)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d77Rw.jpg)

In this figure, it is assumed that $x_0$, $x_1$ and curve $y^{\ast}(x)$ are known coordinates and curve that minimizes functional J. $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are arbitrary constants. Curve $y(x)$ is defined as:

$y(x) = y^{\ast}(x) + ex + f$. Here $x_0+\epsilon_1a \leq x \leq x_1+\epsilon_3c$. Correspondingly, $y_0+\epsilon_2b \leq y \leq y_1+\epsilon_4d$.

In order to make $y(x) = y^{\ast}(x)$ when $\epsilon_1 = 0$, $\epsilon_2 = 0$, $\epsilon_3 = 0$ and $\epsilon_4 = 0$, it is required that

$e = \frac{[y_1 + \epsilon_4d - y^{\ast}(x_1 + \epsilon_3c)]-[y_0 + \epsilon_2b - y^{\ast}(x_0 + \epsilon_1a)]}{(x_1+\epsilon_3c)-(x_0+\epsilon_1a)}$, and

$f = [y_1 + \epsilon_4d - y^{\ast}(x_1 + \epsilon_3c)] - \frac{[y_1 + \epsilon_4d - y^{\ast}(x_1 + \epsilon_3c)]-[y_0 + \epsilon_2b - y^{\ast}(x_0 + \epsilon_1a)]}{(x_1+\epsilon_3c)-(x_0+\epsilon_1a)} (x_1 + \epsilon_3c)$.

Curve $y(x)$ represents a type of 'general' curve that is different from the optimal curve $y^{\ast}(x)$ in terms of its magnitude and two end points. Curve $g(x)$ in the figure can be ignored for now. The functional $J$ is thus:

$J = \ \int_{x_0+\epsilon_1a}^{x_1+\epsilon_3c} F(x, y, y') \,dx $, which is a function of $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3$ and $\epsilon_4$. The differential of $J$ is:

$dJ = \frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_1}d\epsilon_1 + \frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_2}d\epsilon_2 + \frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_3}d\epsilon_3+ \frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_4}d\epsilon_4$.

Since the lower and upper limits of integration are not constant, the Leibniz integral rule for differentiation under the integral sign has to be used:

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_i} = F(x_1+\epsilon_3c, y, y^{'})\frac{d(x_1+\epsilon_3c)}{d\epsilon_i} - F(x_0+\epsilon_1a, y, y^{'})\frac{d(x_0+\epsilon_1a)}{d\epsilon_i} + \ \int_{x_0+\epsilon_1a}^{x_1+\epsilon_3c} \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial \epsilon_i} \,dx $, $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$.

$\frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial \epsilon_i} = \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \epsilon_i} + \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial y^{'}} \frac{\partial y^{'}}{\partial \epsilon_i}$,

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \epsilon_i} = \frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i}$,

$\frac{\partial y^{'}}{\partial \epsilon_i} = \frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i}$. Then

$\int_{x_0+\epsilon_1a}^{x_1+\epsilon_3c} \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial \epsilon_i} \,dx = \frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i} \int_{x_0+\epsilon_1a}^{x_1+\epsilon_3c} [\frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial y}x +  \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial y^{'}}]\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i}  \int_{x_0+\epsilon_1a}^{x_1+\epsilon_3c} \frac{\partial F(x, y, y')}{\partial y} \,dx$.

Let's use $*$ to donate the optimality when $\epsilon_1 = 0$, $\epsilon_2 = 0$, $\epsilon_3 = 0$ and $\epsilon_4 = 0$. Then

$(dJ)^* = (\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_1})^*d\epsilon_1 + (\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_2})^*d\epsilon_2 + (\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_3})^*d\epsilon_3+ (\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_4})^*d\epsilon_4$,

$(\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_i})^* = F(x_1, y^*, y^{*'})\frac{d(x_1+\epsilon_3c)}{d\epsilon_i} - F(x_0, y^*, y^{*'})\frac{d(x_0+\epsilon_1a)}{d\epsilon_i} + \ \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial \epsilon_i} \,dx $.

$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{\partial F(x, y^{*}, y^{*'})}{\partial \epsilon_i} \,dx = (\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i})^* \int_{x_0}^{x_1} [\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^*}x +  \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}}]\,dx + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i})^*  \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^*} \,dx$.

At optimality, curve $y^*(x)$ satisfy the Euler equation:

$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^*} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}}$. Substitute this into the previous equation and integrate by parts, it can be derived that:

$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{\partial F(x, y^{*}, y^{*'})}{\partial \epsilon_i} \,dx = (\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i})^*  [\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} x ]|_{x=x_0}^{x=x_1}   + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i})^* [\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} ]|_{x=x_0}^{x=x_1} $.

It can be derived that:

$(\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_1})^{*} = \frac{a y^{*'}(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_2})^{*} = \frac{-b}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_3})^{*} = \frac{-c y^{*'}(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_4})^{*} = \frac{d}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_1})^{*} = -y^{*'}(x_0) \frac{a x_1}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_2})^{*} = \frac{b x_1}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_3})^{*} = y^{*'}(x_1) \frac{c x_0}{x_1-x_0}$,

$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_4})^{*} = \frac{-d x_0}{x_1-x_0}$.

Substitute those equations above to $(dJ)^*$:

$(dJ)^* = d\cdot(F_{y^{*'}})_{x=x_1} d\epsilon_4 - b\cdot(F_{y^{*'}})_{x=x_0} d\epsilon_2 + c\cdot[F-(F_{y^{*'}})y^{*'}]_{x=x_1}d\epsilon_3 - a\cdot[F-(F_{y^{*'}})y^{*'}]_{x=x_0}d\epsilon_1$.

Is the above derivation correct? If so, compared with Eq (5) from Fomin:

[image: Eq(5), Fomin]

Does this mean that, when evaluate the variation of $J$ based on the optimal curve:

$(\delta J)^* = (dJ)^*$?

Moreover, in the above derivation, $(dJ)^*$ is evaluated at the optimal coordinates $x_0$, $x_1$ and the optimal curve $y^*(x)$. But Eq (5) of Fomin seems to be more general, meaning that Eq (5) can be used for the curve which is not optimal. How can I derive $dJ$ which is evaluated on any curve $y(x)$?

Comment: 2. and 4. $\delta$ and $d$ are more or less the same thing, but $\delta$ is used when a function is changed, while $d$ is used when a scalar is changed.

Comment: 3. If you think of $dy$ as a small variation of a scalar value, then you can think of $\delta y$ as a small variation of a function. One might say very imprecisely that $(\delta y)(x) = d(y(x)).$

Comment: 1. I think that it's practically the chain rule:
$$\delta J = \int \frac{\delta J}{\delta y(x)} \delta y(x) \, dx + \frac{\partial J}{\partial y_i} \, dy_i + \frac{\partial J}{\partial x_i} \, dx_i.$$

Comment: Why $y(x) = y^{\ast}(x) + ex + f$? That's a very limited type of variation.

Comment: I assume $y^{*}(x)$ is the optimal curve, among all smooth and admissible curves. I made $y(x)$ very simple, for the reason that, even among the this simple type of $y(x)$, $y^{*}(x)$ is better (optimal) than this $y(x)$. This simple type of $y(x)$ can make my derivation simpler. More general form of $y(x)$ may be used, but I feel it may lead to the same form of $(dJ)^*$ in the end.

Comment: So you vary the endpoints $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ by adding a linear term to $y^*$? Then you take derivative of $J$ w.r.t. the variations of the endpoints, i.e. w.r.t. $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4$?

Comment: BTW, when you write an equation that is to be displayed on a line of its own, it looks better enclosing it in `$$` instead of simply `$`. Compare
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \epsilon_i} = \frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i}$
with
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \epsilon_i} = \frac{\partial e}{\partial \epsilon_i}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_i}$$

Comment: Yes, I make $J$ a function of those four $\epsilon$. Endpoints are free (free boundary conditions). Since $y^{*}(x)$ is the assumed optimal curve and $y(x)=y^{*}(x)$ when $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$,$\epsilon_3$, $\epsilon_4$ are all zero, $dJ$ must be $0$ when $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$,$\epsilon_3$, $\epsilon_4$ are all zero. That is how I derive $(dJ)^*$. Thanks for the advice too.

Comment: And each of $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \epsilon_i}$ should vanish when $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3=\epsilon_4=0.$

Comment: I think so. When all $\epsilon$ are independent, the corresponding partial derivatives should be zero, and those become the boundary conditions for the Euler–Lagrange equation of the optimal curve to be solved. I just don't know how to derive $dJ$ for any non-optimal curve $y(x)$. Eq (5) of Fomin seems like the general variation of $J$ for any curve.

Comment: @Arbiter In the first two paragraphs of your question, you have summarized how to use Gâteaux variation to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation. Could please you suggest me a reference where these formalism is clearly described?

Answer (score 1):

1. We have a function of three variables — one function $y$ and two real values $x_0,x_1$:
   $$
   J(y; x_0, x_1) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F(x, y(x), y'(x)) \, dx.
   $$
   When all the variables are varied we have
   $$
   \delta J 
   = \left< \frac{\delta J}{\delta y}, \delta y \right>
   + \frac{\partial J}{\partial x_0} \, dx_0
   + \frac{\partial J}{\partial x_1} \, dx_1
   .
   $$
   Here,
   $$\begin{align}
   \left< \frac{\delta J}{\delta y}, \delta y \right>
   &= \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y(x)} \, \delta y(x) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)} \, \delta y'(x) \right) \, dx
   \\
   &= \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)} \, \delta y(x) \right]_{x_0}^{x_1} + \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y(x)} \, \delta y(x) - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)}\right) \, \delta y(x) \right) \, dx
   \\
   &= \left. \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)} \right|_{x=x_1} \, \delta y_1 
   - \left. \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)} \right|_{x=x_0} \, \delta y_0 + \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y(x)} - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)}\right) \right) \, \delta y(x) \, dx
   \\
   \frac{\partial J}{\partial x_0} \, dx_0
   &= -F(x_0, y(x_0), y'(x_0)) \, dx_0 \\
   \frac{\partial J}{\partial x_1} \, dx_1
   &= F(x_1, y(x_1), y'(x_1)) \, dx_1 \\
   \end{align}$$
2. $d$ and $\delta$ are just different notations for what are basically the same thing. The big difference is that $\delta$ is used when a function is changed, while $d$ is used in most other cases. The difference is more pragmatic than semantic.
3. If you think of dy as a small variation of a scalar value, then you can think of $\delta y$ as a small variation of a function. One might say very imprecisely that $(\delta y)(x) = d(y(x)).$ When the variation is done by replacing $y(x)$ with $y(x)+\epsilon h(x),$ one can say that $\delta y=\epsilon h$ i.e. $\delta y(x) = \epsilon h(x).$
4. See point 2.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation. May I ask how does $\delta J$ was expanded as the sum of the three terms as you wrote? Is it the general definition of $\delta J$? Could you also refer any book or literature that the general variation is derived as yours? Thank you!

Comment: It is principally the same as $dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\,dy$ when $z=z(x,y)$ but a product is replaced with an inner product when the factors are functions. Think
$$
dz = \sum_i \frac{\partial z}{\partial x_i} \, dx_i \to \int \frac{\partial z}{\partial x(t)} \, x(t)\, dt.
$$

Comment: My difficulty is to understand $\delta$:  $\delta x$, $\delta y$ and  $\delta J$. That is why I prefer to start the definition by Gâteaux variation, since by that I can just see $\delta$ as a symbol and think $\delta J$ as a limit of derivation wrt. $\epsilon$.

Comment: Do you understand $d$ as in $dx$ and $df$? What is it?

Comment: In your derivation of variation of J, it lacks of terms related with  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial dy/dx}dy/dx$. This term appears in the general variation of J derived by Fomin.

Comment: No, I do have $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)}$ and then, after integration by parts, $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x)} \right)$.

Comment: Is your $\delta J$ the same as Eq (5) of https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHrvy.png ?

Comment: I add my own derivation of the differential of $J$, by making $J$ a function of four independent scalar variables $\epsilon_i$, $i= 1,2,3,4$. These variables can change independently so that the two end points of the curve can move freely. I'm not sure if my derivation is correct, could you please have a look? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the equations
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial x_j} \, dx_j = \pm F(x_j, y(x_j), y'(x_j)) \, dx_j\quad(j=0,1)$$
should have an extra term
$$\pm \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'(x_j)} y'(x_j) \, dx_j.$$
I understand the term, but don't know the best way to incorporate it into the equations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you think of my new derivation? I tried to include as many steps as possible to make the derivation clear. If you think my derivation is not correct please let me know. Thanks in advance.